# how can i get the url of a local folder that placed inside java project folder

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy a file from an external folder to a local folder in Java project folder. The problem is, i don't want to paste the exact url of the local destination folder since it may not work if the project is moved elsewhere. So, is there a way to get the destination folder by code (automatically even when moved)?

This is the function i used for copy

```java
private static void copyToUpload(File source,String name) throws IOException {           
    String tail = source.getName().substring(source.getName().lastIndexOf("."));              
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), (new File("src/"+name+tail)).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Called:

```
> protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
> response) throws ServletException, IOException {
>         File src = new File(request.getParameter("selectedFile"));
>         copyToUpload(src, "hello"); }
```

Expected:

```
src: C:\\..\test.jpg
des: C:\\Test\src\test.jpg
```

Actual:

```
NoSuchFileException
```

Stack trace:

```
>    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
> C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\60788720_1251034635090935_8981200640877264896_n.jpg
> -> src\hello.jpg
>       sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
>       sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>       sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:205)
>       sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
>       java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
>       controller.upload.copyToUpload(upload.java:30)
>       controller.upload.doPost(upload.java:78)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: can you show where are you calling the code? And the full stack trace please

Comment: oh yes, i''ve just edit the post with the information you need

Comment: thanks, and you are positive the source file exists at this path? C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\60788720_1251034635090935_8981200640877264896_n.jpg

Comment: yes, of course, since before accessing to this phase, i've choose this file from a file dialog, and parse its url to the source param

Answer (score 0):

Just put your files in the **src/main/resources** folder

You can get your file by using **ClassLoader.getResource**:

```
String resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("test.jpg").getFile();
        File test = new File(resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running this code (it has similar logic). It runs. I suggest checking if the files exist.

```
public class CopyFilesTest {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CopyFilesTest.class);

    private static Path sourceFile;
    private static Path destinationFile;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepareResources() {
        sourceFile = new File("src/test/resources/testFile.txt").toPath();
        destinationFile = new File("src/test/resources/testFile_copy.txt").toPath();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenExistingFile_expectCopiedFile() {
        Assert.assertTrue(sourceFile.toFile().exists());
        logger.info(String.format("Source file %s exists.\n", sourceFile.getFileName()));

        if (destinationFile.toFile().exists()) {
            logger.info(String.format("Destination file %s exists.\n", destinationFile.getFileName()));

        } else {
            logger.info(String.format("Destination file %s does not exist.\n", destinationFile.getFileName()));

        }

        logger.info("Copying file.");

        Path createdFile = null;
        try {
            createdFile = Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("Failed copying files.");

        }

        Assert.assertNotNull(createdFile);
        Assert.assertEquals(destinationFile.toAbsolutePath().toString(), createdFile.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        logger.info("Files successfully copied.");
    }
}
```

The log from the first run where the destination file does not exist:

```
[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Source file testFile.txt exists.

[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Destination file testFile_copy.txt does not exist.

[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Copying file.
[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Files successfully copied.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And the log from the second run where the file exists from the first run:

```
[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Source file testFile.txt exists.

[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Destination file testFile_copy.txt exists.

[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Copying file.
[main] INFO org.stackoverflow.copyfiles.CopyFilesTest - Files successfully copied.

Process finished with exit code 0
```